# Hover на родителя SCSS

Tags: html, scss, hover

Задача: как сделать так, чтобы при новедении на "hover_elem", "parent" сменил background-color.

```html
<div class="parent">
      <div class="children1">
        <div class="children2">
          <div class="children3">
            <div class="hover_elem"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: а ни как) `css` не умеет подниматься вверх;)

Comment: тут нужна сила `js`!

Comment: всё верно написал @ThisMan, вы могли бы изменить стиль дочернего элемента при наведении на родителя, но никак не иначе, воспользуйтесь объявлением события JS или бросьте эту безумную идею )))

Comment: Даже всемогущий SCSS не может?

Comment: Я бы теперь еще посоветовал прочитать про scss (точнее про css-препроцессоры), судя по всему у вас не правильное представление о нём :-)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const hover = document.querySelector('.hover_elem');
const parent = document.querySelector('.parent');

hover.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
  parent.style.background = 'red';
});

hover.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  parent.style.background = '';
});
```

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}


.hover_elem {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="children1">
    <div class="children2">
      <div class="children3">
        <div class="hover_elem"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```